# if self === top or google.com

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         if (self === top) {
          var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
          antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
         } else {
          top.location = self.location;
         }
      </script>
```

I have this code that does not allow iframes but I want to allow iframes only from google.com how can i do this?

I think the pseudo-code would be
 `if (self === top) or google.com` but dont know how to do this in javascript

Comment: check out `self.location.host` e.g. `if (self === top || self.location.host === 'google.com') {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the host name with `top.location.host` like this:

```
if (self === top || top.location.host === 'google.com') {
  //good to go
}
```

BUT you cannot change the location of the top if the host names are different:

```
if (self != top) {
  document.write('cross domain');
}
if (self.location.hostname !== top.location.hostname) {
  top.location.href = self.location.href; //throws exception
}
```

Throws:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://mbr.domain2.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://mbr.domain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

So, I don't think this is going to do what you want.

Comment: Wouldn't `self.location` return the the URL where the content is hosted, not from where the iframe is included? `top.location` might work, not sure if the included frame has access to that.

Comment: Yes you are right - it should have been `top`, my mistake - let me double check.