# How to restrict website to load only inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, content-security-policy, playframework-2.5

I have two web sites:

- `https://exampleiframe.com` (third-party website),
- `https://example.com` (my website)

I want to restrict `https://example.com` to load only inside iframe of `https://exampleiframe.com`

I have added فاث below CSP in the response header for `https://example.com`.

`"Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' https://exampleiframe.com"`

This policy only restricts when the request is coming from an iframe. But I don't want to load this url (`https://example.com`) anywhere other than this iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to restrict direct access to page via Url and allow show it in iframe only - it's not solvalble with CSP. CSP only restricts Urls for framing (you shown correct CSP for that).

But you can use JavaScript and if [self === top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771876/if-self-top-or-google-com) perform redirect to `/not_allowed` Url.
Myy be it's possible to use some `data-` attribute like `<iframe data-access='framed' src=''></iframe>` and check this attribute by JS inside iframe (if it is accessible). Direct Url will not have such `data-` attribute.

But such check will fail with disabled javascript.